# Formatting Radio Button in Table Data HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, radio-button

```css
html,
body,
p,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
table,
tr,
td,
th,
img,
ul,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

h1 {
  padding: 10px 0 10px 210px;
  font-size: 160%;
  color: blue
}

textarea {
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: Tahoma;
}

table {
  margin-left: 120px;
}

.ta {
  vertical-align: top;
}

td {
  border-top: 20px solid white;
  border-right: 20px solid white;
}

textarea,
input {
  border: 1px solid silver
}

input,
textarea {
  width: 400px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 100%
}

input,
textarea,
td,
button {
  font-family: Tahoma;
  ;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 120%;
  font-weight: bold
}
```

```html
<body OnLoad="document.getElementById('focus').focus();">
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Name:</td>
        <td><input id="focus" type="text" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Date:</td>
        <td><input type="text" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Phone Number:</td>
        <td><input type="text" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell:</td>
        <td><input type="text" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Charger: </td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="charger" value="yes">Yes<br>
          <input type="radio" name="charger" value="no">No<br>
        </td>
      </tr>
```

The problem lies within the radio buttons. This is not the complete code, but the relevant HTML and CSS. The radio buttons appear in the middle of the page as opposed to being in line with the rest of the form. The text associated with the radio buttons is out past the end of the rest of the input blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the width of the `input` elements to 400px

```
input, textarea {
    width: 400px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 100%;
}
```

If you remove that width from the `input` elements everything snaps into place.

```
textarea {
    width: 400px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew it had to be something so simple. '

Comment: You could just change `input` to `input[type='text']` - that will target just the text input boxes and not effect anything else, so you can still style them accordingly